# What is -m do in git remote add

Tags: git

I was hoping

```
git remote add -m <local branch> <origin> <url>
```

would allow me to create a "shortcut" for

```
git push <origin> <local branch>/master
```

via  `git push <origin>`

1. What does `git remote add -m <branch name>` do?
2. Is there any way to make an "alias" command i.e. `git push <origin> = git push <origin> <local branch>/master`?

Comment: Although this question can't really be properly answered, it does bring up a lot of items that probably confuse Git newbies, so I wrote a long answer...

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. Not sure why I get downvoted on this thread when I ask 'dumb' questions. I genuinely don't understand Git's inner workings so I thought asking for understanding is what SO is for? 
[https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emaddem]

I used the command with an understanding that it would do it one way, but actually invoking the command caused it to behave another way. I guess I could keep guessing, so I resorted to SO. Since there wasn't a duplicate, I decided to ask.

All I ask is for those who downvoted to offer a comment with a -1 to why they downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can't get what you want here, because `git push` takes *refspecs*.

#### Long

Let me answer this in several parts, because the question itself is a bit of a problem.

> I was hoping [`git remote add -m ...`] would allow me to create a "shortcut" for [a push command that doesn't make sense in the first place]

It won't, but mainly because that `git push` command doesn't actually make much sense.  We can get to what `git remote add -m` *is* useful for, but before that, we need some good background.

#### Some basic facts about `git push`

Let's start by reviewing `git push` itself.  What `git push` needs, at a minimum, are two pieces of information:

- how to contact some other Git; and
- what to tell that other Git, once contact is made.

The "what to tell" is actually a *list* of one or more things that Git calls *refspecs*, which we'll get into in a moment.  The first part—*how to contact some other Git*—has a long and somewhat sordid history, but the *modern* way to do this is to use a *remote*.

This leads more or less naturally to the syntax:

`git push remote refspec [refspec2 refspec3 ...]`

Note that the arguments here are *positional*, in that the *first* argument<sup>1</sup> after the keyword `push` is the remote.  **A remote is simply a short name, such as `origin`**, that Git uses for several purposes, the most important one being to store a long URL—well, presumably one longer than the six letters `origin`, for instance.  If you accidentally type in a branch name in this position, Git will still treat it as a remote-name:

```
$ git push master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
```

In other words, anything here that looks, to Git, like an ordinary word—not a raw URL, which is allowed, and not something defined using what I called the "somewhat sordid history" either—needs to be defined as a remote, which where the `git remote` command comes in.  We will get to this, but we need to finish off the `git push` command first.

The part *after* the remote name `origin` is a list of some number of *refspecs*.  I have used the word "refspec" here repeatedly without defining it.  [The Git Glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) defines it, rather unhelpfully, this way:

> A "refspec" is used by fetch and push to describe the mapping between remote ref and local ref.

I like to say that in its second-simplest form, it's just a *pair of references separated by a colon*, with `master:master` or `develop:develop` being fine examples.  A *reference* or *ref* here is also defined, this time rather better, in the Git Glossary.  You can see that now for more details, or wait: I'll go into this more in another section below.

I say that this `master:master` form is the *second* simplest form because the *simplest* form of a refspec eliminates the colon and just uses one name.  This means that `master`, which is a valid branch name, is also a valid refspec!  When you write `git branch master` or `git checkout master`, you are using the word `master` as a *branch name*, but when you write `git push origin master`, you are using the word `master` as a *refspec*.

This is worth sitting down and thinking about: **The way a word is used affects its meaning.**  That's true in many human languages,<sup>2</sup> as well as in computer languages like the mini-computer-language that the Git command-line uses.  In Git's case, the position of the arguments to `git push` determines how Git will use them: the first one is a remote, and the rest are refspecs.

We'll come back to this later.  Now let's move on to remotes and `git remote`.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, it's the first *non-flag argument* after the `push` keyword, since you can, e.g., run `git push -f origin ...` for instance.

<sup>2</sup>For example, the English word spelled [*let*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let) can be a verb meaning *to allow*, or a verb meaning *to rent* ("an apartment for let" or "rooms to let").  This particular example is striking, because it is also a noun meaning *obstruct* and a verb meaning *to prevent*, making it an [auto-antonym or contronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) a la *cleave*, to cut apart or, with auxiliary word *to*, to cling together.  For fun, see the Wikipedia link for many more contronyms.

---

#### Using `git remote` to define or modify remotes

As we saw, a remote is a short name that stores a URL.  When you run `git clone` to copy some other Git's repository to your own system, your Git sets up a remote for you, to save the URL you passed to `git clone` so that you never have to type it in again.  Your Git saves this URL under the name `origin`, so that's why you have a remote named `origin`.<sup>3</sup>

If you use `git init`, not `git clone`, to create your repository, you *won't* have a remote named `origin`.  In this case, you are free to create one.  You can call it `origin` if you like, because you can call it anything you want.

To add a new remote—whatever you want to call it—to your existing repository, you can use `git remote add name url`.  Both the *`name`* and the *`url`* are required here, because a remote primarily *is* a name for a URL.  The name and URL are now paired-up, and at this point, you can use `git remote` to make *changes* to it.

The option you asked about, `-m branch`, is just a variation on doing `git remote add` followed by `git remote set-head`, as a single command.  This means its full description is listed under [the `set-head` section of the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-headem):

> Sets or deletes the default branch (i.e. the target of the symbolic-ref `refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD`) for the named remote. Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch. ...

Unfortunately, this bit of information, while correct, is useless on its own.  To see what `set-head`—and therefore `-m`—is good for, we need to look at the way Git handles name-to-hash-ID translation, which is a concept independent of `git push` and `git fetch`.

---

<sup>3</sup>In fact, `git clone` is essentially `git init` in a new directory, followed by `git remote add` followed by `git fetch` followed by `git checkout`.  There are a few extra, optional steps that I've omitted in this short list here, and `git clone` also handles the special case of being interrupted and removing any incomplete repository it may have made, but really, these four steps—five if you count making the new directory as a step—will get you a working clone.

---

#### References: branch names, remote-tracking names, tags, and so on

As I've said elsewhere, Git is primarily concerned with *commits*, and commits—and in fact, all Git objects—are identified by their hash IDs.  The hash ID of any Git object is a big ugly string of letters and numbers, such as `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7` (this is an actual commit in the Git repository for Git).  These things are too unweildy for humans to use, especially since they seem to be totally random (though they are anything but random).

Given that hash IDs are problematic, and that we're constantly growing repositories by adding *new* commits to them (while keeping the old ones), Git has a solution.  These are branch names, tag names, and so on.  Collectively, Git calls these names *references*.  In order to make these different names coöperate, Git places them in [*namespaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), whose definition I'm going to leave to Wikipedia.  It suffices to say here that `master` is short for `refs/heads/master`, while a tag like `v2.3` is short for `refs/tags/v2.3`.

Git uses these references to store hash IDs.  Your Git has a big table, that you can print out at any time using `git for-each-ref`.  This *plumbing command* <sup>4</sup> prints the whole table, or some subset if you say so, and lets you give formatting directives telling it *how* to print it out, but here's a sample of the default output:

```
$ git for-each-ref
5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7 commit refs/heads/master
5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7 commit refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
98cdfbb84ad2ed6a2eb43dafa357a70a4b0a0fad commit refs/remotes/origin/maint
5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7 commit refs/remotes/origin/master
bc1bbc6f855c3b5ef7fcbd0f688f647c4e5b208b commit refs/remotes/origin/next
dfcf84ebfa17eb0bb3b57806fa530e87d8c8f1b8 commit refs/remotes/origin/pu
b2cc3488ba006e3ba171e85dffbe6f332f84bf9a commit refs/remotes/origin/todo
[massive snippage]
e8f2650052f3ff646023725e388ea1112b020e79 tag    refs/tags/v2.17.0
8548c552c627322ac6e8a221d6fe9be531c3aeb1 tag    refs/tags/v2.17.0-rc0
53e83f73a113f0dbfec850d222681ae21eadd834 tag    refs/tags/v2.17.0-rc1
5c35c7ea8cfdb6951a2e3923309d46138e1724b4 tag    refs/tags/v2.17.0-rc2
5b62a68cad663be4cd19fd59d053c57d88811c80 tag    refs/tags/v2.17.1
7f8020239f3b8ebc28299a97ba7db23d74e65447 tag    refs/tags/v2.17.2
```

The big ugly thing on the left is the hash ID, and the name on the right, starting with `refs/`, is the full name of the reference.

There is another basic Git plumbing command, `git rev-parse`, that turns a reference—or a short form of that reference—into a hash ID:

```
$ git rev-parse master
5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7
$ git rev-parse v2.17.0
e8f2650052f3ff646023725e388ea1112b020e79
```

Some Git commands, like `git checkout` and `git branch`, just naturally *expect* a branch name, and expect you to use one *without* the leading `refs/heads/` part.  Other Git commands, such as `git log`, don't: they generally run `git rev-parse` to do the job of turning a name into a hash ID.

When `git rev-parse` is doing this job, of turning a name into the hash ID that most Git commands really need after all, it has a six-step procedure it follows.  This procedure is described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  The `<refname>` here is the literal string you typed in on the command like, like `master` or `v2.3` or `origin/master`:

> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

This rather long sequence is actually very important: it explains a lot about Git, especially in some bad or corner cases.  In particular, if you accidentally create a *tag* named `master`, Git starts acting weird: `git checkout master` still works, but `git rev-parse master` starts telling you about the *tag*, rather than the tip of the branch.

Let's go back to the idea of the table for a moment.  The table records the *current hash ID* of each reference.  Tag names are supposed to be human-readable names for one specific hash ID, and therefore never change, but *branch* names are supposed to be human-readable names for the *latest commit* on the branch.  This means that the mapping from *branch name* to hash ID is constantly changing!  Every time you add a new commit to your `master` branch, your Git changes the result of looking up the name `master`.

But—except for some commands that *know* they're dealing with a *branch* name—looking up the name `master` goes through that six-step process, because Git thinks that maybe `master` is a *tag* name.  So, at step 3 of this process, Git checks the table: is there a `refs/tags/master`?  If not, Git goes on to step 4, and looks up `refs/heads/master`.

This means that if you do accidentally create a *tag* named `master`, *some* Git commands stop at step 3 and get you the hash ID for the *tag*.  Other Git commands, like `git checkout master`, try the name as a *branch* first, starting at step 4 and finding the hash ID from the branch name!  So now, some Git commands show you the *tagged* commit, and others work with the *branch*.

---

<sup>4</sup>A *plumbing command*, in Git, is any command meant for other commands to use to get some particular job done, rather than for ordinary humans to use every day.  That doesn't mean *you* can't use them every day, but they're generally not prettied-up: they generally don't use colors, or run things through a pager if they're long, for instance.  Git's user-oriented commands are called *porcelain* as they are meant to be clean and shiny, as opposed to the icky plumbing behind the porcelain.

---

#### Your own Git updates your remote-tracking names automatically

Some of the references we saw above start with `refs/remotes/`, followed by a remote name like `origin` and another slash.  These are your own Git's *remote-tracking names*.<sup>5</sup>  These act as your Git's method of remembering what the hash IDs were in the *other Git*.

That is, your Git has *your* big table full of references like `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/develop`.  But so does *their* Git: the Git over at the URL listed under `origin` has *its own* `refs/heads/master`, and maybe its own `refs/heads/develop`.  Your Git wants, for several reasons—including to be helpful in general to you—to remember what *their* Git had recorded as *their* master branch.  So your Git *updates* your `refs/remotes/origin/master` to remember the hash ID *they* had under *their* `refs/heads/master`.

Note that these remote-tracking names can be shortened to just `origin/master`.  That's because of step 5 above: if you type in `origin/master`, and your Git has not yet found a hash ID by any of the earlier steps, it gets to step 5, sticks `refs/remotes/` in front, looks in your Git's table, and finds `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  So when you write `origin/master`, your Git turns that into `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which holds the hash ID that your Git saved / updated the last time your Git talked with the other Git at `origin`.  (Whew!)

Every time you run `git fetch origin` (with no refspecs), your Git updates *all* your `origin/*` names.  When you run `git push origin refspec`, your Git updates your one pushed-to `origin/*` name *if* the push succeeds, because if the push succeeds, your Git has just asked `origin`'s Git to *set* one of its branch names, and they accepted, so your Git knows what hash ID they just set.

---

<sup>5</sup>Git traditionally calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, which I think is a poor name, so I have taken to calling them *remote-tracking names*.  That's only a slight improvement, but I think it is an improvement.

---

#### Putting it all together

*OK*, you might say, *but tag-master vs branch-master, well, that's an "I broke something" case.  If I haven't broken anything, how does this tie in with `git remote set-head`?*

Well, look again at the description of what `git remote set-head` does (remember that `git remote add -m ...` is doing a `git remote set-head`):

> Sets ... `refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD`

Now look at step 6 of the gitrevisions process (`git rev-parse` and most Git commands):

> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

What `git remote set-head` is doing is setting things up so that step 6 does something useful—or at least, potentially useful.  Look also at the output I got for my Git repository for Git, particularly this line:

> `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7 commit refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`

The name `origin/HEAD` *already resolves* to a specific commit, namely the same commit as `origin/master`.<sup>6</sup>  I can choose to change this, so that `origin/HEAD` will refer instead to the same commit as, say, `origin/next`.  To do that, I can use `git remote set-head`.

If I use the name `origin`—a remote-name—in a place where Git needs a commit hash ID and where Git invokes `git rev-parse`, my Git will go through the full six-step process.  We can assume that my Git will *not* find a branch named `origin`, for instance, so that it does get to step 6.  Having gotten to step 6, my Git will read my `origin/HEAD` and see that I've told my Git to read my `origin/next`.  So using `git remote set-head origin next` makes *my* `origin/HEAD` link to *my* `origin/next`.

But none of this does much good with `git push`, because when you run `git push`, you don't give a simple reference here, you give a *refspec*.  The refspec is two parts, separated by a colon.  If you run:

```
git push origin origin
```

your refspec is literally `origin`, which figuratively *means* `origin:origin`.  This does nothing useful.  (In fact, it does something odd, which is probably a bug.<sup>7</sup>)

---

<sup>6</sup>There's an important detail here I'm glossing over: this name is a *symbolic reference*.  In effect, it says "I don't have the hash ID myself, someone else—namely `refs/remotes/origin/master`—has the hash ID.  Go look up that name now."  This means that whenever my Git updates my `origin/master`, that also updates the value that `git rev-parse` will produce for my `origin/HEAD`.

<sup>7</sup>Because of the symbolic reference, this turns into `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, which does something that really shouldn't happen at all.

I have set a repository up with a pre-push hook here:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-push
#! /bin/sh
echo pre-push begins
while read line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done
echo pre-push ends
```

This pre-push hook shows us what reference my local Git here will ask the server Git to set, to what hash ID, and what existing hash ID the server has for that reference.  Here is what happened:

```
$ git push origin origin
pre-push begins
refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
pre-push ends
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To [url]
 * [new branch]      origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD
```

On the server, the Git there actually created the reference `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  This server Git bare repository has no `origin` remote at all, so it should not be creating this reference.  The whole thing should have been rejected.

It would make *some* sense for my local Git to ask the server to set the *server*'s `master`—which my Git represents as my `origin/master`, to which my `origin/master` symbolic-reference is connect—but that's not what actually happens.  And, even if that *were* how this translated, that's a request from my Git to the server Git, asking the server to set the server's `master` to the hash ID my Git is recording as the last thing my Git saw in the server's `master`.  That's not very generally useful.  So even if `git push origin/HEAD` resolved a little better locally, the whole idea is not going to go far.

(My local Git on the test machine—which is also the server here, ssh-ing into itself—is slightly out of date, at 2.19.1, but pretty modern.)